# Google ReCaptcha v2 appears at the top of the page (out of view)

Tags: html, css, recaptcha

I don't have this problem on any of my other sites, but when clicking the Recaptcha button to trigger a test, the popup window appears at the top of the page and messes up all the formatting.

https://idasu.uk

Form CSS:

```
.talk form {
    margin: auto;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    background: #1e1e1e;
    width: 450px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: Not sure how much this helps but i cant replicate the issue. There seems to be alot of js consoles errors though.

Comment: @beatnik hi, yeah I don't really know what those errors are about. For me the captcha quiz doesn't even show up in Safari

Comment: Form data sent fine. I havent used v2 for a while. But i know v3 wont always show the captcha quiz. I'd add a redirect after form send or change form action ;)